# Change icon in css content with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$('#test').attr("icon-before", "\f0a3");
```

```css
.test:before {
  content: attr(icon-before);
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<i class="test" icon-before="\f005" id="test"></i>
```

Icons from https://fontawesome.com/icons/star?style=solid and https://fontawesome.com/icons/certificate?style=solid

The Javascript does not properly change the icon, due to not escaping properly I assume. How should I change it to make it work? Other than "\" I tried "&#x" and "&amp#x", but neither of those worked.

Comment: We need to see more of your javascript code to help you out

Comment: Use one more \ to fix

Comment: I tried \\f0a3 in js, but it shows the text "\f0a3" instead of the icon. Setting the icon in html like this: icon-before="\f005" works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magical solution was to use unicode values e.g. \uf0a3.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Font awesome has a Javascript processing. Maybe that's why you can't do this.

Why not play on the classes instead ? This seams way easier than your solution ...

```js
setTimeout(() => $('#test').attr("class", "fa fa-cog"), 1000);
```

```css
#test:before {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>


<i class="fa fa-camera" id="test"></i>
```

Comment: Because I need to stack multiple icons while being able to change them. This would require multiple <i> tags I think?

Comment: If you want to stack icons, you can just use the absolute positioning. Yes, you will need several icons, but as you can see in my answer, you use the exact same JQuery function, so I don't know why you don't play on classes instead of unicodes.

Comment: It was just one approach. I'll try yours as well.